# Remove full parent node if child contains value of parameter

Tags: xml, xslt

Using SAP CPI as tool, the following property is available in the iFlow: 
${property.code}: test

Input

```
<root>
 <row1>
  <value1>value1</value1>
  <value2>value2</value2>
 </row1>
 <row2>
  <value3>value3</value3>
  <value4>value4</value4>
 </row2>
</root>
```

Output:

```
<root>
 <row1>
  <value1>value1</value1>
  <value2>value2</value2>
 </row1>
 <row2>
  <value3>value3</value3>
  <value4>test</value4>
 </row2>
</root>
```

XSLT:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:param name="$code"/>
    <xsl:template match="node()|@*">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>
    <xsl:template match="value4/text()[.='$code']"></xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

The XSLT code only works without using the parameter. (for example replacing '$code' with test would work, but i have to make dynamic..) 
Tried the following links:
https://answers.sap.com/questions/341836/hci-xslt-get-property-value.html
https://answers.sap.com/questions/641167/cpi-xslt---use-of-headerproperty-in-xslt.html

Comment: Please fix the XML. It is not well-formed. And provide a sample of your real XML.

Comment: For information, as you say the XSLT works (if you choose `='test'`) with `<xsl:param name="$code"/>` I guess that your XSLT engine is tolerant, but you should write `<xsl:param name="code"/>` without leading dollar because it's implicit and it's what the official XSLT specification says. The prefix `$` is to be used when you mention the variable in the expressions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try removing the quotes around `$code`...

```xml
<xsl:template match="value4/text()[.=$code]"/>
```